# Python Django error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oauth, django-cors-headers

Hey guys i am getting the below error when i have corsheaders installed, any idea why im getting the below error message as i am out of ideas.

```
installed:
Python 3.7.2

certifi==2018.11.29

chardet==3.0.4

Django==2.1.7

django-cors-headers==2.4.0

django-mssql==1.8

django-oauth-toolkit==1.2.0

djangorestframework==3.9.1

idna==2.8

oauthlib==3.0.1

pytz==2018.9

requests==2.21.0

urllib3==1.24.1

(Oauth) C:\Users\michael.mountford\OneDrive\Programming\matt-mikes-practice\Oauth>Scripts\python.exe mysite\manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03AC8C48>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michael.mountford\OneDrive\Programming\matt-mikes-practice\Oauth\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\michael.mountford\OneDrive\Programming\matt-mikes-practice\Oauth\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\michael.mountford\OneDrive\Programming\matt-mikes-practice\Oauth\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\michael.mountford\OneDrive\Programming\matt-mikes-practice\Oauth\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\michael.mountford\OneDrive\Programming\matt-mikes-practice\Oauth\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\michael.mountford\OneDrive\Programming\matt-mikes-practice\Oauth\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\michael.mountford\OneDrive\Programming\matt-mikes-practice\Oauth\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\michael.mountford\OneDrive\Programming\matt-mikes-practice\Oauth\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\michael.mountford\OneDrive\Programming\matt-mikes-practice\Oauth\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders'
```

Comment: Please post your settings.py file.

Comment: check if `coresheader`  is in `Installed_Apps`.

Comment: Please check you `settings.py` file and check that `INSTALLED_APPS` must contains `coresheader`

Answer (score 7):

This could also be a case of having missed `,` at the end of `corsheaders,` while adding it in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Just check once.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. If 'corsheaders' is in your INSTALLED_APPS and 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware' is in your MIDDLEWARE then something to check is your Virtualenvironment.

Go into the /venv folder and look for the 'corsheaders' folder in /site-packages.

In my case, I had duplicated my project folder so that when I did `pip install django-cors-headers` it installed in the ORIGINAL project's venv. That may be why recreating the venv worked for MichaelMountford.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had the same problem even though I had corsheaders in settings.INSTALLED_APPS. The reason for my problem was that, I wasn't running virtual environment, after I started it, the problem went away. 
Maybe it will help anybody.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out my virtual environment had broken and had to be recreated, worked fine after that.

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative. It would be preferable if you deleted this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `corsheaders` in your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: It already was but i'm still not sure what i did to that instance of Django i eneded up re creating my project and starting and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Figured out, that by some reason Python doesn't see a folder 'corsheaders' in venv/site-packages.  So i just copied 'corsheaders' folder from venv to my project folder like an app on the same level as my app and manage.py belong to.
And it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders` in my project. I made sure I installed the package in the virtualenv with `pipenv install django-cors-headers` but still, it did not work.

I tried to do `pipenv unistall corshearders` and then install it again, but it did not work.

#### Main issue (for me)

I realized the issue was that **inside my virtualenv folder**. With the command `ls /home/youraccount/.local/share/virtualenvs/your-project-name-shUUxxdn3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ | less` (basically your path to `site-packages` inside your `virtualenv`) I went to check if `corsheaders` was present after I run the installation command. To my surprise there was only the folder `django_cors_headers-3.7.0.dist-info` that contained the word `cors` in it.

#### Solution

For me it worked to delete that `django_cors_headers-3.7.0.dist-info` folder manually, and delete the Pipfile.lock and run a fresh install of the cors package. After that I checked that inside `site-packages` there were both `corseheaders` folder and `django_cors_headers-3.7.0.dist-info` folder.